# Super class and abstract test method with JUnit5 tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, junit5, superclass

I migrated unit tests from JUnit4 to JUnit5 and I use Intellij as IDE
With JUnit4, I had some tests implementing two methodes of a test superclass. It seems like I could put the `@Test` on the abstract methods and just override them in subclasses.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

    @SpringBootTest(classes = {TestContext.class})
    public abstract class AbstractTest {
    
        @Test
        public abstract void testOk();
    
        @Test
        public abstract void testKo();
    }
```

And the test

```java
    public class SomeTest extends AbstractTest {
    
        // @Test with JUnit5
        @Override
        public void testOk() {
            //
        }
    
        // @Test with JUnit5
        @Override
        public void testKo() {
            //
        }
    }
```

But with JUnit5, it seems like I have to put `@Test` annotation on the overriding method of the subclass `SomeTest`, otherwise tests are not found. Is there a way to achieve my previous configuration with JUnit5, avoiding to add `@Test` to all subclasses methods ?

Comment: Put them on a method, which calls an abstract method which you then implement.

Comment: I do not get the idea, is it different of what I am doing ?

Comment: Yes it is. Put them on non abstract methods, and in those methods call an abstract method (which you can then implement in your test classes). It is a slight indirection and change to what you have now.

Comment: Indeed, it works. But I still find this alternative a bit weird because it worked easier with JUnit4

Comment: The fact that something worked in X doesn't mean it works the same in Y? It might have work and that could have been unintended, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following M. Deinum recommandation, I ended up with this

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestContext.class})
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    
   public abstract void testOk();
    
   public abstract void testKo();

   @Test
   public void junitTestOk() {
       this.testOk();
   }
    
   @Test
   public void junitTestKo() {
       this.testKo();
   }
}
```